# Retrieve properties from FieldInfo object from instantiated form

Tags: c#

I am trying to get the properties from a public DTO object that comes from a dynamically instantiated form.

```
Form equipmentDialog = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(_lookups.First(d => d.Key == lvwEquipmentCategories.FocusedItem.Text).Dialog, (object)null);

if (equipmentDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    FieldInfo equipmentField = equipmentDialog.GetType().GetFields().First(); //Equipment (DtoEquipment) - there is only one.
    List<PropertyInfo> equipmentProperties = equipmentField.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
}
```

This doesn't give me the properties I am looking for. It just gives me a bunch of properties like IsPublic, IsPrivate etc.

The result i'm looking for is something like this:

```
DtoEquipment test = new DtoEquipment();
List<PropertyInfo> testProperties = test.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
```

This gives me the properties of my DTO object.
But I obviously need to get these properties from the DTO object on the instantiated form.

I have tried casting the FieldInfo as the DTO but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. Use `FieldInfo.FieldType` to get the type of the field.

```
if (equipmentDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    FieldInfo equipmentField = equipmentDialog.GetType().GetFields().First();
    List<PropertyInfo> equipmentProperties = equipmentField.FieldType.GetProperties().ToList();
}
```

Comment: How would I get the values of theses properties? 
    itemDetails[2] = equipmentProperties.First(ep => ep.Name == "Manufacturer").GetValue(equipmentField, null).ToString();

Doesn't work.

Comment: You need to call [propertyInfo.GetValue method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @afm Doesn't work is not helpful, post a new question saying what happens when you try that. You may get quick answers..

Comment: Will do, have to wait 90 minutes though :/